# Combining multiple excel worksheets into a single sheet

Tags: database, vba, excel

I found this vba script which is used to combine the data of multiple worksheets into one master sheet

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Replace Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```

however in my worksheets the first 3 rows are category titles and range from A-BN. I want to alter this code or create a new one that will copy the data from the work sheets so that these category titles aren't repeated in the master sheet. I only want the first 3 rows as the titles and the rest is data.

how can this be achieved?

Comment: What did you try, and what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some like This?

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1:C3").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(3, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 3).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```